mysql threads connected more than processlist and established connectios
Recently we have been facing an issue with MySQL. We use Percona MySQL 8.0.21 and set max_connectios to 7000. Sometimes in peak times, we reach 7000 connections and when we run show status like 'threads_connected' on MySQL, we can see the number of connected threads varies between 6800 and 7000. However, when we run mysql -e 'show processlist' | wc -l we can see that the number of processes on MySQL varies between 4000 and 4200. Also, when we run ss -tan | grep -i estab | wc -l we can see that the number of established connections is between 4000 and 4200. Is it normal?  Should not show prcesslist gives us all threads?

7000 is possible and "high".  I would say that 1000 is suspicious.
But it is hard to say whether it is "bad".  One can have lots of "Sleep" connections; these waste a little memory but don't really hurt.
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running'; -- If that is more than a few dozen, you may have serious problems.
Check for some recent deadlock via SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS;  When you do the PROCESSLIST, see if there are a lot of conflicting queries -- perhaps waiting on each other.
Wilson's requested data will also help us to help you further.

Consider posting TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; logged in a root - so we can see ALL the processes involved.

Answering my own question.
After researching more, I figured out that SHOW PROCESSLIST iterates over list of threads while getting a mutex on threads. MySQL docs. What I understand from documentations is that MySQL loops over threads and extracts their information while preventing new threads to be added. Meanwhile, when the information is getting extracted some other threads might finish their jobs and they are not counted in the results. Table performance_schema.threads can be used instead.
